# Retrieve current page in Internet Explorer using C#

Tags: c#, html, api, internet-explorer, hook

I am currently looking for a solution to a problem I have. My aim is to be able to get the Source code of HTML pages that have been looked at. Originally I was going to just go through the history of IE and then get the source code for every visited site, however this isn't feasible at the moment, and I am looking for a method, if possible, which would simply pull the current page that is being looked at in Internet Explorer, and pull the source code.

Is it possible that a client application could do this? Hook into Internet Explorer and grab the source code? If so, how, what references etc. Please note I am not looking to use my own Browser in the client, but rather the application Internet Explorer.

Thanks!

Internet Explorer 8 / 9.

Comment: Yes, this is possible to do in several different ways.  My question to you is, what have you tried thus far?  Posting some code/what you have done will take you much farther than what you have at this time...

Comment: Which Internet Explorer?

Comment: Like I said the method I have used, and have coded is by pulling the IE History, and going through each page, grabbing its source and moving on. And as such, I haven't tried coding this as I don't know how to go about doing it. Maybe getting the window with Spy++ and then something else :S ?

Comment: And internet Explorer 9

Comment: Are you writing a separate application that communicates with IE, or an IE extension that gets plugged into the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via two methods.

First would be an http proxy like [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/)

Second would be with MSHTML (COM library: Microsoft HTML Object Library)

```
Dim tWindows As ShellWindows = new ShellWindows
For Each tInstance As IWebBrowser2 in tWindows
  Console.WriteLine(tInstance.LocationURL)
Next
```

Comment: I added a referebce to that (MSHTML) but still telling me that ShellWindows doesn't exist :/ ? EDIT: Fixed had to import Microsoft Internet Controls .. testing.